# Ruby Net::HTTP execution expired

Tags: ruby, net-http

Using Net::HTTP, I periodically find that the code below rescues from StandardError with a message of "execution expired", despite the fact that the web server logs from the accessed URL show the corresponding response was sent quickly.  When the web server logs show a response that takes more than 5 seconds, I generally see the code rescue from Timeout::Error.

What case would cause the code below to rescue from StandardError with "execution expired" **instead of** rescuing from Timeout::Error?

This code is running in a multi-threaded program on a relatively ancient Ruby 1.9.3, on a platform that does not support newer versions of Ruby.  Although the program is multi-threaded, the code shown only runs on a single thread.

```
begin
  connection = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  connection.open_timeout = 5
  connection.read_timeout = 5
  connection.start do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/reader_events")
    request.body = body
    response = http.request(request)
  end
rescue StandardError => std_error
  log "error sending event to server: #{std_error}"
rescue Timeout::Error => error
  log "timeout sending event to server"
end
```

Comment: Try putting your `rescue Timeout::Error` block before the other rescue block. In Ruby, most exception classes inherit from StandardError, so it wouldn't surprise me if Timeout::Error does as well. If that's the case, then the error would be both a kind of StandardError and a kind of Timeout::Error. And the first matching `rescue` handler wins.

Comment: @HenrikN Good catch. Printing `Timeout::Error.ancestors` shows that it indeed inherits from `StandardError`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because how `rescue` works. Take a look at documentation page for [`Exception`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Exception.html) class. Basically you can create many exceptions that inherits from a single one, and handle all of them using rescue with the parent class:

```
begin
  ...
rescue Exception => exception
  ...
end
```

This code will rescue all types of exceptions as `Exception` is the root (other exceptions inherits from it). In your case `Timeout::Error` inherits from `RuntimeError` which inherits from `StandardError`:

```
Timeout::Error.ancestors
  => [Timeout::Error, RuntimeError, StandardError, Exception, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

As the result it is kind of `Exception`:

```
Timeout::Error.new.is_a?(StandardError)
  => true
```

Another thing in your case is that interpreter will check each `rescue` statement from the top to the bottom. It means that first it will check if the `exception` is kind of `StandardError` and later it will move to the following `rescue` block. You should always list `rescue` blocks from the most specific to the most general one.

Change the order of `rescue` blocks to fix the code.

Comment: Ah, simple answer.  Thanks!